# Fill dynamic vector using EIGEN library

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

I have to fill a vector with values within a for loop using EIGEN. Im trying something like that...

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){ 
  VectorXd s;
  for (int i=0,i<10;i++){
     s(i) = (double) i;
  }
return 0;
}
```

i can compile it, but when i run the program i get this error:

> dynamic: /usr/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:425: Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase::Scalar& Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase::operator()(Eigen::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix; Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase::Scalar = double; Eigen::Index = int]: Assertion `index >= 0 && index < size()' failed.
>   Abgebrochen

I know that i can easily achieve that using the std::vector class, but i want to do it with eigen because i have to do a lot of matrix operations after that.

Thank you!

EDIT: for my application i don't know the size of the vector at compile time. I want to find out whether there is any similar method like `vector::push_back` in eigen.

Comment: *Assertion `index >= 0 && index < size()` failed.* You can *easily* do the same out-of-bounds access with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Maikel advised me. I could solve my problem with the resize function as follows;

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){ 
  VectorXd s;
  for (int i=0,i<10;i++){
     s.resize(i+1);
     s(i) = (double) i;
  }
return 0;
}
```

@Jonas made me realize that I know the size of the vector before the loop, so I can  resize once before the loop.

About the resize function in the documentation in Eigen could be found:

> "The resize() method is a no-operation if the actual matrix size doesn't change; otherwise it is destructive: the values of the coefficients may change. If you want a conservative variant of resize() which does not change the coefficients, use conservativeResize() "

therefore, when it could be better to use conservativeResize() to assure the values wont be lost.

Comment: I am not sure if the `resize` function guarantees to keep the old values. Do you have no way of telling how much you are going to need in runtime?

Comment: when do you have the info for the size of the vector? do you need to resize in a loop or can u do it before it? resizing in a loop is usually inefficient.

Comment: I know the size of the vector before the loop, that is a great point. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to reserve space for the vector. This would be same for `std::vector`.

Try this

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // resize to 10 elements
  auto vec = Eigen::VectorXd(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    vec[i] = i;
  }
  std::cout << vec << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That's the problem, that i dont know the size of the vector at compile time. With std::vector i can do that with the push_back method. Is there any way to achieve the same with eigen? Thanks!

Comment: You could use the the `resize` function. See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html